# AFNetworking - add "image\jpeg" content type to AFImageResponseSerializer

Tags: ios, facebook, afnetworking

I'm trying to load a picture from Facebook's source (a picture I've  uploaded through my app and saved it's source).
I'm using AFNetworking to handle all my networking needs but when i'm trying to load a picture from:

[http://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10314676_10152739718934904_452946709678730535_n.jpg?oh=7e73d62e46c33e541e559e07e12bf275&oe=54B7E8CB&**gda**=1421866048_e364ab835ea15826e7ff28c8382ac085](http://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10314676_10152739718934904_452946709678730535_n.jpg?oh=7e73d62e46c33e541e559e07e12bf275&oe=54B7E8CB&__gda__=1421866048_e364ab835ea15826e7ff28c8382ac085)

(which opens in the browser, or in a regular http get request i'm setting in a http generator) but from the AFNetworking it always get a bad request (403) error..

I think that because the response from the server will be image\jpeg and i've ready that by default it doesn't work with AFNetworking..

How can i add it to the serialzer? or should i just write a new http request ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've ended up using:

```
-(void) loadPictureFromUrl:(NSString*)urlString {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if ( !error )
                                   [_httpRequestDelegate httpResponseReceived:nil responsedData:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]];
                               else
                                   [_httpRequestDelegate httpRequestReturnedError:nil withError:error];
                           }];
}
```

instead of fighting with AfNetworking - which is usually awesome but has an issue with what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

`imageView.imageResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"image/jpeg", @"image/jpg"];`